# Get textfield when user want

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I have created image `upload file` text field in the form. If the user wants multi-choose field. I want to give rights to the user that 'user' to choose the number of files.

Let me show you my text field.

```html
<div class="form-group col-lg-10">
    {!! Form::label('file', 'Upload Chart:') !!}
    {!! Form::file('file', null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
```

- Should I need jquery?
- What should i do in Jquery?

Comment: Please share your try ?

Comment: Actually, I dont what should i do,... therefore i asked here? @C2486

Comment: what you are saying is not clear, please provide more info ?

Comment: User can choose multi file. @C2486

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html5, you can simply add the `multiple` attribute to support multiple file uploads.

`<input type="file" name="field_name_for_files" multiple>`

I don't know about the `Form` helper you are using, but it should accept `'multiple' => 'multiple'` in the third parameter array.

Try this:

`<div class="form-group col-lg-10">
    {!! Form::label('file', 'Upload Chart:') !!}
    {!! Form::file('file', null,['class'=>'form-control', 'multiple' => 'multiple'])!!}
</div>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added the `multiple` attribute in my form but, its showing me one file only.

Comment: With the single file upload field, you should be able to select multiple files from your local hard drive. Maybe I didn't understand you question, I thought you needed to allow users to upload multiple files at once.

Comment: Yes I want to upload multi-file choose by user. but your `multiple attribute` idea did not work for me.

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati : select two or more file from your hard drive at the same time, to add multiple file, `multiple attribute` should work